# Is there a way to read session tags from within an AWS lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-lambda-go

I have an AWS lambda written in Go which is invoked using:

`aws lambda invoke …`

I am setting session (sts) tags before invoking the lambda. Is there a way from within the lambda to get the session of the caller and read the tags which were set?

Comment: I am also trying to achieve the same in TS. Did you find the answer ?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the answer is no. It’s not possible to get sts session tags from within the lambda.